# hair particles is clipping throught mesh

Tags: particles

I'm pretty new to blender and I'm trying to create hair for a character but the hair keeps clipping through the [image]mesh and makes it look terrible what should I do?

Comment: the option *[X] Deflect Emitter* should prevent this. Try to turn it off and on again, and click on the hair. It should be moved above the surface. Or try to increase the *Distance* (maybe it's too small for your model?)

Comment: its enabled with enough distance its still clipping